# React Native Modal w/ Redux Delay in Toggling

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a global button that is located in the root navigator and I also have a custom modal component that has its own reducer and actions. I am calling a toggle function inside the global button to toggle the modal, but when I compare the speed of the toggling on a modal that uses an ordinary state, it is much faster than with redux state. Why is this so?

Modal:

```
<Modal
   visible={this.props.showCoinModal}
   animationType="fade"
   transparent={true}
   onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}
>
```

Mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  showCoinModal: state.coinModal.showCoinModal
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onToggleCoinModal: () => dispatch(toggleCoinModal()),
  }
}
```

Modal Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  showCoinModal: false
}

const coinModalData = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_COIN_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        showCoinModal: !state.showCoinModal
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: I  would suggest using Redux for you business logic state, and keeping the UI state like in this case simple with `this.setState({...})`.

Comment: "this.state" is created with the component and stays inside a component hence setState is much faster as compared to redux which is handling the state globally,

Comment: I already figured out what's causing the delay, it's the middleware logger of redux, I jsut removed it and it's fast again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out what's causing the delay, it's the middleware logger of redux, I just removed it and it's fast again